# Loss of value of a variable in node.js, how it's possible to solve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, asynchronous

I'm using node's `socket.io` library and want to create socket clients in `init` method and use that "pool" of clients in another method, but loss that value, code example below:

```
import * as socketio from 'socket.io';

class SocketService {
  public io: socketio.Server;
  public server: any;
  public socketClients: Map<number, string[]> = new Map();
  public a;

  constructor(server: any) {
    this.server = server;

    this.initSocket();
  }

  public initSocket() {
    this.io =  socketio(this.server, {path: '/api/socket'});

    this.io.use(async (socket: socketio.Socket, next: express.NextFunction) => {
      this.a = 'value';
    });
  }

  public notifyUsers(req: any): any {
    console.log(this.a); // undefined
  }

}
```

I'm don't understand why `a` is `undefined` int `notifyUsers` method, can you help me guys?

Comment: Where is notifyUsers called?

Comment: This is route handler, by '/notify/:id', so it's called in router file, when I do request in postman, I'm get "undefined"

Comment: @LGSon I think you'll find that arrow functions don't define their own block scope, so `this.a` will match the notifyUsers scope which should match the class level scope if the class is instantiated with `new`.

Comment: Can you show that code please, Konstantin?

Comment: @Paul agree, I'm tried to promisify that function, where I'm use the sockets, but it's too doesn't help

Comment: @Paul http://snippi.com/s/avlvaqv

Comment: @LGSon, it's not, I was referring to what's happening in the init function. NotifyUsers is a member function of the class, so it shares its instance prototype and therefore `this`

Comment: Konstantin, post all code in the question, not in links please.  And I meant we need to see the calling code (the route handler).

Comment: Do you understand that `io.use()` is middleware and will be called on some future incoming request?  It seems likely that you are just calling `notifyUsers()` BEFORE an incoming request as set the value of `this.a`.  It also appears that storing a value from one middleware call in `this.a` is probably a faulty design since that gets called over and over again for different user connections so you will just be constantly overwriting it with the last value to occur.

Comment: What is the `public` keyword?

Comment: @1252748 just read about typescript)

Comment: @KonstantinKudelko That's what I was thinking. Somehow missed the typescript tag. Thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00 do you know how better create a "pool" of socketClients?

Comment: guys, thx for all of your answers, I solved that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue, cause is my instance of Service has been created several times and overwrite my variable.

Solution: Create instance one time in main `.ts` file and export it.